# How can I execute a stored procedure using linq in a background/alternate thread

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, multithreading

In my app I am using the open xml sdk to generate a word document and write the file to the response.output stream for the user to download.

At the time that the letter is generated I also need to call a SP via linq data context to update a row in my db.

I think that I need to execute this SP in a seperate thread so that I can simultaneouly write the file to the output. my method looks like this...

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArge e)
{
    //call sp to update

    //create letter and send to client
 }
```

Is this feasible or should I avoid seperate threads?

Comment: I'm not able to understand. Why you want use a separated thread?

Comment: LINQ to SQL...but my problem wasnt thread related. I was jumping to conclusions lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `PageAsyncTask`, `Page.RegisterAsyncTask`, `Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks()` etc functions and classes to do async processing. For more information read this article on [eggheadcafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060918.asp).

But I don't think updating a row will take longer than creating a word doc.

Comment: Please do blog about it if you use this technique.

Comment: I need to check more into what my problem is. I will report back

Comment: My actual problem was this update panels and postbacks but you get the answer for the async task solutions